# Comparing if datetime.datetime exists or None

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running a small app on Google App Engine with Python.
In the model I have a property of type DateTimeProperty, which is datetime.datetime. When it's created there is no value (i.e. "None").
I want compare if that datetime.datetime is None, but I can't.

```
if object.updated_date is None or object.updated_date >= past:
  object.updated_date = now
```

Both `updated_date` and `past` is datetime.datetime.

I get the following error.

> TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to NoneType

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: There is no way that you can be getting that error on that line if both are instances of `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `and`, not `or`.

You may also want to use `is None`.

**EDIT:**

Since you've determined that `object.updated_date` *isn't* `None`, this only other possibility is that `past` *is* `None`.

Answer (score 8):

Given that the previous discussion seems to have established that either of the variables could be `None`, one approach would be (assuming you want to set `object.updated_date` when either of the variables is `None`):

```
if None in (past, object.updated_date) or object.updated_date >= past:
  object.updated_date = now
```

point being that the check `None in (past, object.updated_date)` may be handier than the semantically equivalent alternative `(past is None or object.update_date is None)` (arguably an epsilon more readable thanks to its better compactness, but it is, of course, an arguable matter of style).

As an aside, and a less-arguable matter of style;-), I strongly recommend against using built-ins' names as names for your own variables (and functions, etc) -- `object` is such a built-in name which in this context is clearly being used for your own purposes.  Using `obj` instead is more concise, still readable (arguably more so;-), and has no downside.  You're unlikely to be "bitten" in any given case by the iffy practice of "shadowing" built-ins' names with your own, but eventually it will happen (as you happen to need the normal meaning of the shadowed name during some later ordinary maintenance operation) and you may be in for a confusing debugging situation then; meanwhile, you risk confusing other readers / maintainers... and are getting absolutely no advantage in return for these disadvantages.

I realize that many of Python's built-ins' names are an "attractive nuisance" in this sense... `file`, `object`, `list`, `dict`, `set`, `min`, `max`... all apparently attractive name for "a file", "an object", "a list`, etc.  But, it's worthwhile to learn to resist this particular temptation!-)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you mean:

```
if object.updated_date and object.updated_date >= past:
```

If it's truthy (which implies not null), we check that it's *also* >= past.  This uses short-circuit evaluation, which means the second condition isn't checked if the first is falsy.

Comment: It doesn't check nullness, it checks falseness. This will catch `None`, but it will also catch some non-`None` values as well.

Comment: True, @Ignacio.  I've clarified now.

Comment: What falsy values can a `datetime.date` value have? I'm not aware of any `date` that can evaluate `False`. `datetime.date` values range from `date(1,1,1)` to `date(9999,12,31)` which all evaluate `True` in a boolean context. If you can be certain the `object` is a `date` or `None` then there's no problem with "other non-None falsy values" - because there aren't any.